# Why do Firebase SDK's connect to upload.video.google.com?

Tags: firebase

At my company, a proxy configuration error highlighed something very unusual in the log which we don't really like - namely access to "upload.video.google.com" (see anonymized full log below). Can someone tell my why a Firebase SDK adresses such a... spooky resource and whether video is really uploaded?

The app is a Swift project making use of the pods FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseCrashlytics and FirebaseRemoteConfig.

The full error log:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x7fe647163c00) s: upload.video.google.com i: ipproxy.myorg.com>",
    "<cert(0x7fe647078600) s: ipproxy.myorg.com i: MYORG Root CA 01>"
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/firebase-myproject/namespaces/firebase:fetch?key=ABC, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/namespaces/firebase:fetch?key=ABC, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001046070 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x600002dde370>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x7fe647163c00) s: upload.video.google.com i: ipproxy.myorg.com>",
    "<cert(0x7fe647078600) s: ipproxy.myorg.com i: MYORG Root CA 01>"
)}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <B73299B8-37F5-4C2F-A09A-B856F962B6EC>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <B73294B8-37F5-4C2F-A49A-B856F962B6EC>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x600002dde370>, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.}
```